# Is there a better approach to use years in an ordered list than the value attribute?

Tags: html, html-lists, semantics

For a list of portfolio-items, which all have a year, I am assuming an ordered list is the way to go semantically since it is a list ordered by year. However, I don't want the value to be a number starting at 1, but the year in which the item was created. To reach this result I wrote the following.

```
<ol>
  <li value="2015">Last made item</li>
  <li value="2015">Item before that</li>
  <li value="2014">Earliest item</li>
</ol>
```

However, this

- reverses the natural order of `<ol>`'s;
- Uses the same marker multiple times;

so I would think this isn't exactly the best way to accomplish this. So I would like to know:

1. Do you have any suggestions on how to do improve this?
2. Are there any more reasons why this should not be done this way?

**Edit:** Please note the list has already been sorted, but I want the marker to be the year in which the item was created. This happens using the method mentioned earlier (see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnwvavwh/), too), but I'm doubting this is the best way to go, semantically.

Comment: List items don't have a value attribute. You should be using a custom data attribute (`data-`) instead.

Comment: "orderd-by" is misguided. In html ol tag does not mean that it sorts the items of the list in an order. It just prepends a number or a letter to each list item so that it looks like a numbered list.

Comment: @j08691 It does, though; [see w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li.attrs.value)

Comment: @tibzon No, I get that it doesn't order the list automatically. My question isn't so much about functionality as about semantics. I will edit my question to hopefully explain it better.

Comment: @FMJansen : Yes that is better now. But I am not quite sure what do you actually want to achieve? What do you mean by _marker to be the year in which the item was created_ ? You have achieved what you want (in the fiddle you provided). Do you want to know whether it is the best way to do it and any alternatives?

Comment: If you are not willing to use javascript/jquery, according to my opinion, what you have done is totally fine as you have got repeating years too. If the years are not repeating and also in a perfect ordering, you can use an approach like **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/q9p1twsd/)**

Comment: @tibzon `Do you want to know whether it is the best way to do it and any alternatives?` yes! :) And thanks for the alternative. I'll create an answer with your solution and own later thoughts, probably tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Do you have any suggestions on how to do improve this?

### Alternative A

A good alternative would be a structure like this:

```
<article>
  <time datetime="2015">2015</time>
  <h1>Last made item</h1>
  <p>Description</p>
</article>
<article>
  <time datetime="2015">2015</time>
  <h1>Item before that</h1>
  <p>Description</p>
</article>
<!-- etc. -->
```

This assumes the items in the list could be representable as a "*independent item of content*" ([W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element)) and a portfolio-item, which was the type of item in my question, meets this specification.

### Alternative B

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <time datetime="2015">2015</time> Last made item
  </li>
  <li>
    <time datetime="2015">2015</time> Item before that
  </li>
  <!-- etc. -->
</ol>
```

With CSS you could remove the marker if desirable. Thanks to [TotempaaltJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238310/totempaaltj) for this alternative.

Either way the year is now machine readable as being time, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time).

> This element is intended to be used presenting dates and times in a machine readable format. This can be helpful for user agents to offer any event scheduling for user's calendar.

Read [Bruce Lawson's post on the `time` tag](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2012/best-of-time/) to see this `datetime` notation works/is allowed.

> Now, “fuzzy dates” are possible:
> `<time datetime="1905">` means the year 1905

---

## 2. Are there any more reasons why this should not be done this way?

When using `<li value="year">` you're losing the meaning of the number as being a year.

---

## Other thoughts

[@Michael_B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31666629/1318983) gave me more insight into the meaning of `<ol>` and `<ul>` and @tibzon [gave an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662740/is-there-a-better-a-approach-to-use-years-in-a-ordered-list-than-the-value-attri/31666629?noredirect=1#comment51637190_31662740) with the `reversed` attribute of an ordered list, see [his fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9p1twsd/).

Comment: Hey when I originally read your answer I didn't see the "Other thoughts" at the end! If you found my answer helpful/useful please consider an upvote.

Comment: @Michael_B Haha, sure! if I recall correctly, I wasn't able to do so earlier on due to my low reputation :')

Answer (score 1):

tag is not going to do any sorting algorithm for you. HTML is a markup language which is only used for displayed purpose.  is only used for a order-list and you have to do the ordering your self.

If you content is generated using a backend language, then you can use the backend language to do the sorting algorithm and print whatever number you want in front. And since you don't want the number starting with 1, I would suggest you using  instead.

For example, if you are using PHP for the backend language, you can use the following code:

```
echo "<li>".$year." - $content."</li>";
```

I am not sure your sorting algorithm so can't help with that. Hope this help.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but it isn't about sorting (see my edited question). It's about the semantics of the HTML I'm using and its content.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an ordered list in HTML and specify a starting number other than 1, you can use the `start` attribute in the `ol` tag.

```
<ol start="2014">
  <li>Last made item</li>
  <li>Item before that</li>
  <li>Earliest item</li>
</ol>
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bksh2xka/)**.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on your revised question and new comments, I see that your focus is primarily on the semantics of the code. Specifically, is this code...

```
<ol>
  <li value="2015">Last made item</li>
  <li value="2015">Item before that</li>
  <li value="2014">Earliest item</li>
</ol>
```

... semantically correct?

The answer is yes. Semantically, you're totally fine.

#### Features of the HTML Ordered List <ol>

An ordered list (`ol`) simply means the order of the list matters, whereas in an unordered list (`ul`) the order of each list item is unimportant, and each list item can be sorted randomly because the order doesn't matter.

Here's what the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element) says about ordered lists:

> *The `ol` element represents a list of items, where the items have been*
>   *intentionally ordered, such that changing the order would change the*
>   *meaning of the document.*

Here's how [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) puts it:

> *The `<ol>` and `<ul>` both represent a list of items. They differ in the*
>   *way that, with the `<ol>` element, the order is meaningful. As a rule of*
>   *thumb to determine which one to use, try changing the order of the*
>   *list items; if the meaning is changed, the `<ol>` element should be*
>   *used, else the `<ul>` is adequate.*

Here's what the HTML5 spec **doesn't** say:

- It doesn't say the numbers or letters marking each line item have to be numbers or letters. They don't.
- It doesn't say the numbers or letters marking each line item have to be in chronological order. They don't.
- It doesn't even say that each line item must have a number, letter or other marker. It doesn't. It can be left blank (see CSS [`list-style-type: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type)).

These examples, where the order of the list has meaning, are valid and semantically correct HTML.

```
<ol>
  <li value="2025">Portfolio 1</li>
  <li value="2010">Portfolio 2</li>
  <li value="1999">Portfolio 3</li>
  <li value="2005">Portfolio 4</li>
  <li value="2015">Portfolio 5</li>
  <li value="2014">Portfolio 6</li>
</ol>

<ol type="a" reversed>
  <li>Portfolio 1</li>
  <li>Portfolio 2</li>
  <li>Portfolio 3</li>
  <li>Portfolio 4</li>
  <li>Portfolio 5</li>
  <li>Portfolio 6</li>
</ol>

<ol style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li>Portfolio 1</li>
  <li>Portfolio 2</li>
  <li>Portfolio 3</li>
  <li>Portfolio 4</li>
  <li>Portfolio 5</li>
  <li>Portfolio 6</li>
</ol>
```

**[Run examples in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bksh2xka/1/)**

Comment: Hey! It does, but now the 'Last made item' seems to be made in 2014 and the 'Earliest item' in 2016, while it should at least be the other way around. Thereby, what if both the first and second item are made in 2014?

Comment: Semantically, you're totally fine. An ordered list (`ol`) simply means the order of the list matters, whereas in an unordered list (`ul`) the order of each list item is unimportant and can be sorted in any way. This means that whatever order your list needs to be in, and whatever years need to be assigned as values, is valid and semantically correct HTML. Chronological numbering is common, but not required.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I talked about this with someone and we came to the conclusion it may be okay, but the meaning of the year is not represented properly. I'll create an answer with your answer and those thoughts.